# AWS API Signature Does Not Match

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-selling-partner-api

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "<below>",
            "code": "InvalidSignature"
        }
    ]
}
```

Message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. The Canonical String for this request should have been [[redacted]]

However my inputs are

```
<cfscript>
    // define a struct for arguments
    args={}
    // Input fields
    args.requestMethod='GET'
    args.hostName='[[hostname]]'
    args.requestURI='[[requestURL]]'
    args.requestBody=""
    args.requestHeaders={}
    args.requestParams={}
    args.signedPayload=true
    args.excludeHeaders=[]
    args.regionName='us-east-1'
    args.serviceName='execute-api'
    args.amzDate=aDate
    args.dateStamp=dateStamp
    args.signatureData={}
    args.tokenData={}
</cfscript>

<cfhttp method="put" url="[[URL]]" result="result">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#signatureData.AUTHORIZATIONHEADER#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-amz-access-token" value="#tokenData.access_token#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-Amz-Date" value="#aDate#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: What version of Coldfusion?

Comment: ColdFusion 2021

Comment: What does the doc say about signing method and AWS secret key and what did you do to pass that information to the API?

Comment: @AndreasRu These      args.requestMethod='GET'
   args.hostName='sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com'
   args.requestURI='/externalFulfillment/inventory/2021-01-06/locations/43cd8cd4-a944-4fa8-a584-5e3b3efdb045/skus/efptestsku2'
   args.requestBody=""
   args.requestHeaders={}
   args.requestParams={}
   args.signedPayload=true
   args.excludeHeaders=[]
   args.regionName='us-east-1'
   args.serviceName='execute-api'
   args.amzDate=aDate
   args.dateStamp=dateStamp

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I have done 
1- Authorization
2- Update inventory
3- Get Inventory
4- Get Orders